# Prepared statements with varying parameters

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

All I need is to know how to have a mysqli_stmt_bind_param that can accept 1-4 strings. With placeholders ("?"), in mysqli_stmt_bind_param, only "$stmt, "s", $Interest" will work when 1 interest is searched for or "$stmt, "ssss", $Interest" when 'Any Interest' is searched for.

Thanks!

```
    $Interest = $_GET['interestId'];

$sql = "SELECT * from User WHERE (Interest1 = '$Interest' OR Interest2 = '$Interest' OR Interest3 = '$Interest') OR '$Interest' = 'Any Interest';";


        echo "<h1 class='contact-intro'>";
        echo " Welcome to the business card library for $Interest! </h1>";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);
//Prepare the prepare statements
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "SQL statement failed";

} else {
    //Bind parameters to the placeholder(s)
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $Interest);
    //Run parameters inside database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    //   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
      $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
(lots of echos.......)
```

UPDATED FULL CODE AND DESCRIPTION OF ISSUE.

Comment: What do you mean my _when my second parameter gets checked_? Which parameters does that refer to? The SQL you have here as posted does not include any parameters/placeholders and the variable $Interest would be directly expanded in the `$sql` string.  The SQL itself should include `?` placeholders for mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Comment: My bad. I (frequently) mix up the prepare and param lines. I know that it should have ? placeholders. I just didn't put them. I'm specifically asking for a second parameter that can be 1-4 strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the values for your placeholders in an array variable. And in mysqli_stmt_bind_param() you can use splat operator `...` - like in the code below, so you can process varying numbers of placeholders and its values for a single table field.

You can do something like this:

```
$interest_array = array('basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'basketball');
$s_marks = str_repeat("s", count($interest_array)); 
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $s_marks, ...$interest_array);
```

**This:**

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $s_marks, ...$interest_array);
```

**Will be treated as:**

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $interest1,$interest2,$interest13, $interest4);
```

**Your updated code (haven't tested):**

```
$Interest = $_GET['interestId'];
$sql = "SELECT * from User WHERE (Interest1 = ? OR Interest2 = ? OR Interest3 = ?) OR ? = 'Any Interest';";
$placeholder_count  = substr_count($sql, '?');
$s_marks = str_repeat("s", $placeholder_count); // creates sss string
$interest_array = array_fill(0, $placeholder_count, $Interest); // creates an array of the same values.

echo "<h1 class='contact-intro'>";
echo " Welcome to the business card library for $Interest! </h1>";

 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($link);

 if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "SQL statement failed";
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $s_marks, ...$interest_array);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

The rest of the code will adopt depending only on the number of placeholder in the sql string.

Comment: Unfortunately this code did not return any results for a single $Interest or 'Any Interest'. It only returns a blank page. Also, in my editor, it pointed out that there should be a semi-colon after $Interest) in the array_fill. In case this helps for any other checks!

Comment: There's a missing ';' at the end of `array_fill(..)`.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I've got it working Karlo! But I want to make sure I didn't mess with anything. I removed the "}" at the end and followed up with $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
          $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
**(echos and such)**

Does this nullify the statement or is it still safe? Thanks!

Comment: It is safe. You can also do mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); after your while loop.

Comment: Perfect! Working like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this?

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * from User WHERE (Interest1 = ? OR Interest2 = ? OR Interest3 = ?) OR ? = 'Any Interest';");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $Interest, $Interest, $Interest);

if ($stmt->execute()){
    echo "<h1 class='contact-intro'>";
    echo " Welcome to the business card library for $Interest! </h1>";
}else{
    echo "SQL statement failed";
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code does not return results when a single $Interest  or when 'Any Interest' is present in the execution (forgive my lack of proper coding description if this is hard to parse).